Emoji data from Firestore for user reactions has a bad performance
I'm trying to store user reactions for every single item in a LazyColumn in a Firebase Firestore and then fetch this data. Everything is OK, and the data is successfully fetched, but if any emoji selected, it appears in all LazyColumn items. One more thing: the updated numbers for every emoji are blinking (hiding and appearing) without a stop. I hope the following code samples have a good explanation.


Fetching Data From Firestore
@Composable
fun GetReacts(
    reactsViewModel: ReactsViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    eventsItem: EventsItem,
    fixtureByIdResponseItem: MatchByIdResponseItem
) {
    val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    firestore.collection("reactions")
        .document(fixtureByIdResponseItem.fixture!!.id.toString())
        .collection(
            (
               ((eventsItem.player!!.id)!! *
                (eventsItem.team!!.id!!)) /
               eventsItem.time!!.elapsed!!
            ).toString()
        ).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val result = task.result
                val documents = result.documents
                if (documents.size > 0) {
                    //Love
                    reactsViewModel.getLoveReacts(
                        fixtureId = fixtureByIdResponseItem.fixture.id.toString(),
                        customId =
                        (((eventsItem.player.id)!! *
                                (eventsItem.team.id!!)) /
                                eventsItem.time.elapsed!!).toString(),
                        react = "love"
                    )
                    //Party
                    reactsViewModel.getPartyReacts(
                        fixtureId = fixtureByIdResponseItem.fixture.id.toString(),
                        customId =
                        (((eventsItem.player.id) *
                                (eventsItem.team.id)) /
                                eventsItem.time.elapsed).toString(),
                        react = "party"
                    )
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    //
    val loveCount = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val partyCount = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val coolCount = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val sadCount = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val angryCount = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    reactsViewModel.loveReactsResponse.apply {
        when (this) {
            is EmojiResponse.Loading -> {}
            is EmojiResponse.ReactFailure -> {}
            is EmojiResponse.ReactSuccess -> {
                loveCount.intValue = this.data.size
            }
        }
    }
    reactsViewModel.partyReactsResponse.apply {
        when (this) {
            is EmojiResponse.Loading -> {}
            is EmojiResponse.ReactFailure -> {}
            is EmojiResponse.ReactSuccess -> {
                partyCount.intValue = this.data.size
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}

Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .weight(5f)
        .padding(5.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp)
    ) {
        if (loveCount.intValue > 0) {
            Text(text = loveCount.intValue.toString())
        }
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(15.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.love),
            contentDescription = "Love"
        )
    }
    .... and so on
}

Inside the item
val isUpdated = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
if (isUpdated.value) {
   GetReacts(
      eventsItem = eventsItem,
      fixtureByIdResponseItem = fixtureByIdResponseItem,
   )
}

